# How to arrange plots in specific positions on a grid in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am trying to plot multiple plots (of different sizes) onto a grid, using specific coordinates. To do this, I am creating a treemap using the `treemap` package to get coordinates and then, using these coordinates, Im trying to place my individual plots. Hopefully my example below will explain better my problem.

To begin, I create some barplots and then, I create a treemap, like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemap)
#create data
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
             var2 = runif(3),
             var3 = runif(3),
             var4 = runif(3),
             size = c(10, 5, 3),
             labels = c(1:3))
# Basic barplot
p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var2)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
p2 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var3)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity")
p3 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var1, y=var4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")

#create treemap
tm <- treemap(df,
       index = "labels",
       vSize = "size",
       palette = "Set2")
```

If we take a look at the treemap object `tm`, we can see that it provides the coordinates of the treemap shown below, where `x0`, `y0`, `w`, and `h` are the coordinates.

```
> tm$tm
  labels vSize vColor stdErr vColorValue level        x0    y0         w     h   color
1      1    10      1     10          NA     1 0.0000000 0.000 0.5555556 1.000 #66C2A5
2      2     5      1      5          NA     1 0.5555556 0.375 0.4444444 0.625 #FC8D62
3      3     3      1      3          NA     1 0.5555556 0.000 0.4444444 0.375 #8DA0CB
```

[image: treemap]

So, what Im trying to do is to take my three barplots `p1`,`p2`,and `p3` and place them into the treemap so that `p1` will be in position `1` of the treemap.... `p2` will be in position `2` etc...

For clarity, My desired result would look something like this:
[image: treemap of plots]

Any suggestions as to how I could do this? I tried using the `patchwork` package but ran into issues of the plots overlapping... but im open to suggestions using any package (eg `gridExtra` or just `ggplot`)

**EDIT**
to clarify things a little, as per the answer given by Peter below in relation to the `patchwork` package, I cant manually input the coordinates as the plot layout (I was originally using the `area` function in `patchwork` and inputting the coordinates of the treemap into the `area` function). But, as mentioned in the comments below, if I have numerous barplots, and the size and shape of the treemap changes, then I cant manually input the layout values. I am trying to find a way to automate the process

Comment: What exactly did you do with `patchwork` that didn't work out? I don't know that I've seen it overlap before

Comment: Essentially and naively, I took the coordinates from my treemap, multiplied them by 10 and rounded them to whole numbers. I then used these numbers as my plot layout. But this will cause the plots to overlap due to the coordinates having the similar values.

Comment: But how exactly did you use those numbers? Like did you use them in some way for the widths & heights arguments, or some other parameter?

Comment: I was using the coordinates `x0`, `y0`, `w`, and `h` as the `area` for my plot layout. The `area` function can take 4 arguments as top, left, bottom and right. I was, effectively, inputting my treemap coordinates into the `area` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires some arithmetic, and isn't perfect, but should be a start toward using `patchwork`'s more complex layout options. There are a couple tricks to address:

- `treemap` scales its dimensions based on the viewport, which means the positions it calculates depend on the viewer in e.g. RStudio's plot pane. Instead, it's not strictly necessary, but you should probably decide on an aspect ratio to make sure the positions of boxes are something you'd want.
- You need to convert the decimal positions & sizes to whole numbers, not simply by multiplying by some number and rounding, but by finding the denominator of their fractional equivalent and multiplying by that. For example, the first box has a width 0.55555, which is 5/9; to get integers, we need to know that this box should be 5 units wide out of a total of 9 units. Taking the maximum width & height are arbitrary; the point is just to get one that isn't equal to 1.0.
- Adding and subtracting 1 from the different dimensions isn't the best but was an easy-enough way to get e.g. one box that goes from 1 to 5, and the next from 6 to 9.
- The order of plots isn't right but the sizing is...Haven't figured out why, but to try diagnosing this I added labels to each plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(treemap)
library(dplyr)

asp <- 1.25
tm <- treemap(df, index = "labels", vSize = "size", palette = "Set2", sortID = "labels",
              aspRatio = asp)
denoms <- tm$tm %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(w:h, names_to = "direction") %>%
  filter(value < 1) %>%
  group_by(direction) %>%
  slice_max(value, n = 1) %>%
  mutate(denom = MASS::fractions(value) %>%
           stringr::str_extract("\\d+$") %>%
           as.numeric()) %>%
  select(direction, denom) %>%
  tibble::deframe()
denoms
#> h w 
#> 8 9
areas <- tm$tm %>%
  mutate(across(c(x0, w), ~. * denoms[["w"]]),
         across(c(y0, h), ~. * denoms[["h"]]),
         top = y0 + 1,
         left = x0 + 1,
         bottom = top + h - 1,
         right = left + w - 1) %>%
  select(top:right) %>%
  purrr::pmap(function(top, left, bottom, right) patchwork::area(top, left, bottom, right)) %>%
  purrr::reduce(c)

patchwork::wrap_plots(p1, p2, p3, design = areas)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really clever answer and a great starting point. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`patchwork` seems to work fine:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)


design <- "
  11122
  11122
  11133
"
p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(design = design)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: So this works fine if I manually input the grid coordinates or `design`. But if I have, say, 10 or more barplots, then manually inputting the coordinates becomes cumbersome. I am trying to automate the process by using the coordinates provided by the treemap. Additionally, the treemap would change shape and size if there are more barplots... so I cant input the layout manually

Comment: That's a fair comment. It is not a huge burden using `patchwork::design` unless you have lots of different design configurations for 10 or more barplots or the coordinates for each plot area are critical.

Comment: I will edit my question a bit to reflect this issue